# ReferenceError: 'getMainImage' is not defined but it is

Tags: component, joomla-3.3.x, javascript

There is a problem with this page:

http://www.pubsaregreat.co.uk/culture?category=18&view=pubs

It is not showing images or the Google map, I've debugged it in the Console and it is showing:

```
ReferenceError: getMainImage is not defined
```

I have checked through all of the code and the 'getMainImage' is defined within the component (it's a custom component) and it has previously worked - it is also being loading by the browser.

The getMainImage function is as follows:

```
function getMainImage(venueId, container){
    jQuery('<img id="'+venueId+'_img" src="<?php echo JURI::root().'administrator/components/com_inapub/proxy.php?getphoto=main&venue_id=';?>'+venueId+'" />').load(function(){
            jQuery(container +' :first').replaceWith(this);
        });
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of the API?

Comment: Yes, using the correct (and latest) version of the API

Comment: I've looked through all JS files your importing and inline script, and cannot see the function `getMainImage`. I only see where you're calling it. Can you add the code you're using to define the function?

Answer (score 1):

Just some spare of the moment (possible) solutions:

**Option 1:**

Try wrapping your function in document read:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function getMainImage(venueId, container) 
    {
        $('<img id="'+venueId+'_img" src="<?php echo JUri::root().'administrator/components/com_inapub/proxy.php?getphoto=main&venue_id=';?>'+venueId+'" />').load(function(){
            $(container +' :first').replaceWith(this);
        });
    }

});
```

**Option 2:**

Try making `getMainImage` a global function:

```
getMainImage = function(venueId, container) 
{
    jQuery('<img id="'+venueId+'_img" src="<?php echo JUri::root().'administrator/components/com_inapub/proxy.php?getphoto=main&venue_id=';?>'+venueId+'" />').load(function(){
        jQuery(container +' :first').replaceWith(this);
    });
}
```